# KOTLIN: Glide Image Not Loading into Fragment From Firebase-Storage

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-glide

Glide seems not to be loading images from a specified path in Firebase-storage . Desite being no error in my code and the image uploading error free, I still do not get an updated Fragment page on loading.

Code to Declare :

```
 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (requestCode == RC_SELECT_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK &&
            data != null && data.data != null
        ) {

            val selectedImagePath = data.data
            val selectedImageBmp = MediaStore.Images.Media
                .getBitmap(activity?.contentResolver, selectedImagePath)

            val outputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            selectedImageBmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, outputStream)
            selectedImageBytes = outputStream.toByteArray()

            Glide.with(this)
                .load(selectedImageBytes)
                .into(imageView_profile_picture)

            pictureJustChanged = true
        }

    }



        override fun onStart() {
            super.onStart()
            FirestoreUtil.getCurrentUser { user ->
                if (this@HomeFragment.isVisible) {
                    edittextPersonname.setText(user.name)
                    editTextBio.setText(user.bio)
                    editTextTextEmailAddress.setText(user.email)
                    edittextage.setText(user.age)
                    if (!pictureJustChanged && user.profilePicturePath != null)

                        
                        Glide.with(this)
                            .load(StorageUtil.pathToReference(user.profilePicturePath))
                            .apply(RequestOptions()
                                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_circle))
                            .into(imageView_profile_picture)

                }
            }
        }
```

Below are my library packages from Gradle:

//glide

```
 implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'

    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Some reason, Android Kotlin Glide v4 requires that you declare the "apply plugin" library in your gradle project twice ie

First instance:

[image: First Declaration of The "APPLY PLUGIN"]

Second Instance:

[image: Second Declaration Instance]

Comment: I'll appreciate if anyone has any other simpler way to do it

Comment: Please copy text next time instead of images